# connection string dependancy injection identity server v3

Tags: connection-string, autofac, thinktecture-ident-server, identityserver3

I am using Thinktecture Identity Server V3 and having issues working out how to make the dependancy registration use different connection strings for 2 different repositories. See code below;

```
options.Factory.Register(Registration.RegisterType<IRepository<ScopeWrapper>>(typeof(MongoRepository<ScopeWrapper>)));
options.Factory.Register(Registration.RegisterType<IRepository<User>>(typeof(MongoRepository<User>)));
```

Thanks,

Ed